# Does survey R package allow me to do beta regression?

Tags: r, missing-data, survey, multiple-imputation, beta-regression

I have a complex survey dataset with a response (dependent variable) bounded between 0 and 1, where I have applied multiple imputation to the dataset to account for missing data. The response formally speaking is a percentage, which is a summary of two numbers. However, I cannot recover those two numbers to employ binomial regression model. I did linear regression, but I do not feel good about the results.

$Q$: Does survey package allow me to do beta regression? If so, is there any example code available? I am aware that I can use as.svyrepdesign, but I was given a masked survey design and I am not sure how much loss of precision will be introduce by as.svyrepdesign besides possible noisy multiple imputation.

Comment: No, but there is a wrapper package `svyVGAM` which integrates `survey` and `VGAM`, and `VGAM` can do beta regression. In theory, it has the `betaff` function which I am 92% sure is the beta regression family, but I haven't actually tried it. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/svyVGAM/

Comment: @AlexJ Thanks. I will check it out.